# Select and copy row directly above matching value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a working code that looks for a value and copies the entire row, pasting it to the relevant sheet.

I would like to amend the code, so that it copies the entire row above the found value, rather than the row of the value.

Can anyone suggest a simple amendment to allow me to select the row above?

```
Sub Prod()
Sheets("BJ").Cells.Clear
Sheets("Master").Range("A1:A2").EntireRow.Copy Destination:= _
Sheets("BJ").Range("A1")
Dim MyRange, MyRange1 As Range
Sheets("Master").Select
LastRow = Sheets("Master").Range("K65536").End(xlUp).Row
Set MyRange = Sheets("Master").Range("M1:Q325" & LastRow)
For Each c In MyRange
If c.Value = "BJ" Then
If MyRange1 Is Nothing Then
Set MyRange1 = c.EntireRow
Else
Set MyRange1 = Union(MyRange1, c.EntireRow)
End If
End If
Next
If Not MyRange1 Is Nothing Then MyRange1.Copy Sheets("BJ").[a3]
End Sub
```

Comment: add [`offset property`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff840060(v=office.14).aspx) where required.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to copy the row directly above the *ActiveCell* to the next open row of another worksheet:

```
Sub Dural()
    Dim sh2 As Worksheet, N As Long
    Set sh2 = Sheets("Destynation")
    N = sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    If ActiveCell.Row = 1 Then
        MsgBox "Nothing above"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Copy sh2.Cells(N, 1)
End Sub
```